# Is DNase treatment necessary before RNA sequencing?

Tags: dna-sequencing, rna-sequencing

Is it necessary to treat total RNA with DNase before sequencing it? In particular, if the library prep relies on a poly-A enrichment, is it necessary to remove DNA, knowing that genomic DNA does not have as much polyA as mRNA?